# $x^{3}-x-2=0$ how do I find the roots?

Tags: cubics

I can't seem to find a way to change this equation into its irreducible form to solve it:
$$x^{3}-x-2=0.$$

It should have 1 real root and 2 complex roots.

Comment: Please check your equation.  If the $-x$ is supposed to be $+x$, then the problem is tractable.  If not, then the roots are all horrible.

Comment: [Cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients)

Comment: well i have tried to change it to (y+1)(y+2)(y+3)-2=0 by going backwards but that didn't get me very far either

Comment: The roots are really horrible, even the real one -
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+x%5E3+-+x+-+2+%3D+0

Comment: You can use  *Cardano's method*.

Comment: @Bernard is correct. Cardano made an evergreen contribution to cubic equations.

Comment: @Sid: Actually, Cardano stole the method from *Tartaglia*, who explained   Cardano the details under the seal of secret…

Comment: @Bernard thats interesting, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x) = x^3 -x-2 $$

To solve: $$x^3 -x-2 =0$$

As you have mentioned in the problem, you are aware of the nature of the roots. That is: 2 complex and 1 real. This can be found by studying the behaviour of the discriminant. The demand is to unearth these roots.

First let us determine if this real root is positive of negative. Notice

$f(0) = -2$ and $f(2) = 4$

The function is continous and therefore must be cutting the x axis once. These values were chosen arbitrarily just to see if the REAL root is positive or negative. We have now determined: it is positive.

Subsititute $$x= t+\frac{a}{t}$$

As you said you will use this for the future, this is what you must substitute into the depressed cubic with 1 real and 2 complex roots.

“a” and “t” are both constants. “t” is a constant chosen by us in order to make the expression simpler. You will see why later.

$$x^3 -x-2 =0$$

$$(t+\frac{a}{t})^3 -(t+\frac{a}{t})-2=0 $$

Expand this one:
$$t^3+3ta+3\frac{a^2}{t} +\frac{a^3}{t^3}-t-\frac{a}{t}-2=0 $$

Let us collect like terms.

$$t^3+t(3a-1)+\frac{1}{t}(3a^2 - a)+\frac{a^3}{t^3}-2=0 $$

I want to chose such an “a” so that the middle two terms will cancel out in order for the expression to simplify.

## $$(3a-1) = 0 \cap (3a^2 - a) = 0$$

$$a= 1/3$$

The expression now becomes:

$$t^3+\frac{a^3}{t^3}-2=0 $$

Multiply by $t^3$
and substitute $a=\frac{1}{3}$

$$t^6-2t^3+(\frac{1}{27})=0 $$

Notice the above expression can be made as a quadratic by substituting $t^3 = p$

$$p^2-2p+(\frac{1}{27})=0 $$

By the quadratic formula
$$p = \frac{9+\sqrt(78)}{9}$$

Substitute all back to x

Recall:
$$p = \frac{9+\sqrt(78)}{9}$$
$$t^3 = p$$
$$x= t+\frac{a}{t}$$
where $$a= 1/3$$

Here is a link to all three solutions on wolfram. If you want a method to obtain the other two complex roots comment here.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=7953c4ea52a4873d32cc72052f3dcb10&title=Solve%20for%20X%20Calculator&theme=blue&i0=x%5E3%20-%20x%20-2&podSelect=&includepodid=Input&includepodid=Result&podstate=Result__Show%20steps&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1

Comment: amazing method, and just some observations i think you misswrote it should be : -t - a/t after the "expand this one": and in the next line you changed the "+ a^3/t^3" to *a^3/t^3.

Comment: I edited this. That's for noticing. If you have any other questions feel free to ask

Comment: Why did not you consider the other root of p in the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the equation is supposed to be $x^3+x-2=0$, most people would 
start with the rational root theorem.  The leading coefficient is $1$ and the constant term is $2$, so any rational root would have to be one of $\pm\frac{1}{1}$ or $\pm\frac{2}{1}$.  If you plug in $x=1$, you get $0$, so divide the left side by $(x-1)$ to get $x^2+x+2$.  Set this last equal to $0$ and use quadratic formula to find your two complex roots.

Comment: The equation is $x^3 \color{red}-x-2=0$.

Comment: you can check  (y+1)(y+2)(y+3)-2=0 if it's any easier

Comment: Re-read the problem. Are you interested in finding all three roots or just the real one?

Comment: I'm interested in all three for future math problems.

Comment: Ok I will make a solution. After I find the sole real root, can you take it from there by dividing and forming a quadratic equation... or should i find the complex roots as well?

Comment: @Bernard  I know that.  I'm assuming there's a typo.  The OP has yet to respond to my comment above.

Comment: @B.Goddard no, it's x^3-x-2=0

Comment: @Sid yes i can do the quadratic after that

Answer (score 0):

Its a cubic of type x³ - x - 2 = 0, To solve this let us assume x = y + z and substituting in the original equation we get (y+z)³ - (y+z) - 2 = 0, this can be rearranged further of the form 
y³ + z³ + (3yz - 1)(y + z) -  2 = 0
Put 3yz + 1 = 0 which implies z= 1/3y,
Putting this in above equation we get 
27y³ + 1/27y³ - 2 = 0
Solving this as a quadratic in y³ we get 
Solution for y and subsequently z and then required x. And while taking the roots take account of complex cube roots too to get non real root

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think i found an error.Your (y+z)^3 should look like this (a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3

Comment: Its the same just rearranged (a+b)³ = a³ + b³ + 3ab(a+b) and i took the (a+b) common with the x in the expression which also equals (a+b) so i wrote directly

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment, but restricted by that format.

$$
f(x) = x^3-x-2
$$
[image: funciton]

$$
\begin{align}
  x_{re} &= \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{3 \left(\sqrt{78}+9\right)}+\sqrt[3]{27-3 \sqrt{78}}\right), \\[5pt]
%
  x_{\pm} &= \frac{\left(-1\pm i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{78}}+i \left(\sqrt{3}\mp i\right) \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{78}+9}}{2\ 3^{2/3}} 
%
\end{align}
$$
with numeric values of
$$
\begin{align}
%
 x_{re} &= 1.52138 \\
%
 x_{\pm} &= -0.76069 \pm 0.857874 i \\
%
\end{align}
$$

To see all roots, resolve the complex plane. The dark line is the contour of value $0$.

[image: complex]

The $0$ contours are combined below, blue for Re, red for Im:

[image]

Comment: Anyone  Can use a calculator and find the roots. Notice the OP is asking for a method to find the roots

Comment: @Sid: The contribution here is being able to see the curve and the roots.

Comment: i think the OP knows the function is continuous and there are curves in polynomials. The OP even knows the nature of the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^3-x-r=0$

Solution:

$X = (81 r^2 - 12)^{1/2} - 9 r$

$A = X^2/12 - 1$

$F = X (27 r^2 - 4)/18$

$G = (A^3 - 27 F^2)^{1/3}$

$Q= \begin{cases}-(-1)^{1/3}G\\(-1)^{2/3}G\\G\end{cases}$

$x=X/6 + 3 F/(Q - A)$